# Where to get data for axis of rotation of solar system bodies?

Tags: orbital-elements, jpl-horizons, rotation, ephemeris, spice

Where can I get data for the axis of rotation of the (major) bodies of the solar system?

For each solar system body, I want to get a unit vector of its axis of rotation (at a specified point in time).

Are there any sources where I can get this data directly? Else, what other data could I derive this from and with what methods?

I have no experience using ephemerides or astronomical coordinates, and have just started trying to understand the JPL Horizons documentation, but am concerned from my first readings that I will not be able to directly find the data I am looking. Is the SPICE system a more appropriate place to look?

I would greatly appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: This is an interesting question and a bit of a challenge to answer because trajectories are determined by gravitational effects not only of the Sun but to a lesser extent by the big planets (Jupiter, Saturn, Uranus, Neptune) which cause the Sun to wobble so much that the solar system barycenter is often outside the Sun itself. So the question is "rotation about what exactly".

Comment: From [JPL's Horizons](https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/horizons/app.html)  or [Skyfield](https://rhodesmill.org/skyfield/) (if you like or want to try Python), you can get instantaneous velocity and vectors pointing to the solar system barycenter and to the Sun and take the cross-products but I don't know if that's exactly what you need mathematically. Functionally, Horizons is fine if you don't mind downloading, if you want to run locally use SPICE or Skyfield both get their data from the same [JPL Development Ephemerides](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jet_Propulsion_Laboratory_Development_Ephemeris)

Comment: I'm no expert; better wait for an authoritative expert before taking those cross products and calling them "axes of rotation" ;-)

Comment: I *think* you might want the SPICE Planetary Constants Kernel (PCK); have a look at this [short PDF on the PCK](https://naif.jpl.nasa.gov/pub/naif/toolkit_docs/Tutorials/pdf/individual_docs/19_pck.pdf) which is part of the SPICE tutorial (and references the IAU Working Group on Cartographic Coordinates and Rotational Elements which is the original authoritative source)  and see if it's what you're looking for and I can try and turn it into an answer

Comment: @astrosnapper thanks for this pointer, I think that looks very promising. Trying to dive further into the rest of the SPICE docs & Skyfield. Also, reviewing Skyfield ( thanks for that ref uhoh ), I saw this section on a [Planetary Constants Manager](https://rhodesmill.org/skyfield/api-planetary.html#skyfield.planetarylib.PlanetaryConstants) - does this work with the PCKs ?

Comment: @angust Yes, it looks like that routine in Skyfield loads the PCK file; the current version of the PCK file at NAIF is [pck00010.tpc](https://naif.jpl.nasa.gov/pub/naif/generic_kernels/pck/pck00010.tpc) which you could call `read_text()` on

Comment: These appear on page 402 of the Explanatory Supplement to the Astronomical Almanac (3rd edtion).  They appear to be the same as what's in the pck00010.tpc file mentioned above, but might be in an easier to digest format in the book.

Comment: From the [Horizons manual](https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/horizons/manual.html#obsquan): 32. Target north-pole RA & DEC "Right ascension and declination of the target body's north-pole direction"